# Создать архив bash tar с Git

Tags: git, bash, tar

Захожу в нужную директорию, внутри лежит папка с git репозиторием, делаю команду

```
tar -czf git-ru.tar.gz git-ru
```

по идею от должен заархивировать в tar.gz, но он просто не видит эту папку. не знаете почему на этот запрос пишет ошибку ??

> tar: go-ru: Cannot stat:No such file or directory

Comment: а папка с git репозитарием называется git-ru?

Comment: нет, это введено для теста здесь сейчас)

Comment: А у пользователя, под которым выполняете команду, есть необходимые права на директорию, которую хотите упаковать? Попробуйте добавить параметр v (выводить информацию по каждому файлу), возможно, будет показана причина.

     tar zcvf test.tar.gz ./test

упаковывает полностью директорию ./test со всеми файлами и поддиректориями (в том числе и скрытыми).

Comment: спасибо, попробую! сейчас уже правда решила проблему через   

git archive master | bzip2 >../go-relaweb-ru.tar.bz2  

  
но после приходится длеать лишнее действие